# Can I create a class with multiple dynamic methods with different return types?

Tags: scala

```
object GoodReturnType extends Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(method: String)(args: Any*) = {
    method match {
      case "foo" => 25
      case "bar" => 14
    }
  }
}
```

Method *applyDynamic* of *GoodReturnType* object has *Int* return type. As expected, invocations of its dynamic methods return *Int* too.

```
scala> GoodReturnType.foo() 
res0: Int = 25
```

If we try to add another dynamic method with different return type, return type of *applyDynamic* will be most common type (which is *Any*). So as all dynamic methods.

```
object BadReturnType extends Dynamic {
  def applyDynamic(method: String)(args: Any*) = {
    method match {
      case "foo" => 25
      case "bar" => 14
      case "baz" => "muahahaha!"
    }
  }
}

scala> BadReturnType.foo() 
res1: Any = 25
```

Is it possible to have a class with multiple dynamic methods with different return types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible in principle because you are dispatching based on dynamic information.  Thus, even if you had a response that was typed a particular way, the calling code wouldn't know which type was returned from the available set.  You can use `Either` to express this explicitly if you want (e.g. `Left(5)` and `Right("muahaha")` would return `Either[Int,String]`), but fundamentally you can't retain your static typing after going through a dynamic dispatch step.  If you're not going to use this as a dynamic dispatch step, why not just put the method in directly?

Comment: >why not just put the method in directly? Just a syntactic example, as simple as possible. Asked this question because I'm curious if it is possible to create "dynamic" orm: user.findById(id:Id):User; user.findAll():List[User], user.whereAgeGt(21):List[User]; As you see, return types are different. My guess was "trait Record extends Dynamic" with parser inside invokeDynamic method, but this will not work, as I understand

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot. There are a fixed, predetermined set of `Dynamic` methods to which all non-statically checked references are mapped. The JVM does not support method resolution based on return type alone, so you have to pick a single implementation for a given argument signature

If you have not already, study [SIP 17: Type Dynamic](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/type-dynamic.html).